# The "override_settings" in TestCase is not work

Tags: django, testcase

I used "override_settings" in my test case, and I want to test DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES of REST_FRAMEWORK in the test case. When I tested my api, it didn't work.

```
my settings.py:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '60/min',
        'user': '500/hour',
        'custom': '200/day',
    }
}

test api:
@throttle_classes([AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle])
def test_api(request):
    pass


TestCase:
    @override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
            'anon': '600000/min',
            'user': '5000000/hour',
            'custom': '200000/day',
        }
    })
    def test_api(self):
        from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
        print(api_settings.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES)
        print(api_settings.user_settings)
        from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle, api_settings as throttling_setting

        print(AnonRateThrottle().get_rate())

        print(id(throttling_setting))
        print(id(api_settings))

        print(id(AnonRateThrottle().THROTTLE_RATES))
        print(id(api_settings.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES))
        print(id(throttling_setting.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES))

        url = 'api'
        for i in range(100000):
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I want the test case to work, but it asserts in the state of 429.
I print the id of "apisetting", "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES" , which is the same, but the "THROTTLE_RATES" id in the "AnonRateThrottle" instance is not the same, the value is not the same. The value is "{'anon': '60/min', 'user' : '500/hour', 'custom': '200/day',}". Please help me, I am going crazy.

Comment: Looks like it is a known issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6030

Answer (score 0):

The throttle of drf is worked by cache. I clear the cache with every request to make it work.